# Laravel Orderby specific column value

Tags: php, laravel-5

How can I order by a column value in Laravel 5?  For example, I want to do the equivalent of this:

```
select * 
from table 
order by column = 'Morning', 
column = 'Afternoon', 
column = 'All Day' asc
```

I am using query builder in laravel 5.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this for your query using Laravel's Fluent query builder

```
$myQuery = \DB::table('myTable')
  ->select('*')
  ->orderBy('columnName1')
  ->orderBy('columnName2', 'asc')
  ->get();
```

Then you can `dd($myQuery)` to see what it gets for you.

Also, if you replace `->get()` with `->toSql()` you'll return a string of the query that is being executed which is great for debugging if your query doesn't seem to be working.

Hope that helps you get started!